# Error "Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: json, nginx, https, axios, nuxt.js

I'm running a "universal" Nuxt project on NGINX+MYSQL+PHP Ubuntu 18.04 server. Some pages use Axios to get data from a database (JSON files created by PHP). The project is working fine on dev and production mode. Server using nginx as a reverse proxy (localhost:3000 -> localhost:80).

But after I installed HTTPS and SSL certificates (DigitalOcean manual: How To Secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 18.04) server starts to show error in production mode:

```
 ERROR  Request failed with status code 404                                                                

  at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
  at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
  at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
  at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I tried an example of nginx configuration from Nuxt official site. But Error keep appears.

My config file /etc/nginx/site-available/web_site.com

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    "text/html"                 epoch;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
    default                     off;
}

server {
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name web_site.com www.web_site.com;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/web_site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/web_site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /basemysql {
    auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.web_site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = web_site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name web_site.com www.web_site.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

The app fully functional until you try to reload it.  An error appears every time I'm trying to reload any page that has Axios.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Redirection from HTTP to HTTPS causing the error.
I deleted these configurations and it works fine.

```
server {
    if ($host = www.web_site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = web_site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name web_site.com www.web_site.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```